# Why is ffmpeg bundled with my Electron app?

Tags: electron, electron-builder

When I built my Electron app for production, I noticed `ffmpeg.dll` was included. Why is ffmpeg bundled with Electron?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may know that electron uses chromium for desktop applications building.Chromium has a fork of `FFMPEG` that it builds from source to generate the `ffmpeg.dll` file that goes to Electron builds for Windows.
You can read more about it from this [link](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/third_party/ffmpeg/+/41268576ad9a8b760287101f4f58d0ef468798af)